# How to declare a global Object Class that can be used project wide?

Tags: javascript, svelte

Simple question today (I hope). Where do I declare a object class that I can use project wide in a Svelte 4 app?

For arguments sake, lets say I want to declare a new car object class as such:

```
class Car {
        constructor() {}
        make = '';
        model = '';
        year = '';
    }
```

And then I want to use project wide like:

```
const myCar = new Car();
```

Where do I declare this in Svelte?

I've tried this in the app.d.ts file, but its not working.

Comment: [Don't do it.](https://www.forrestthewoods.com/blog/global-variables-are-evil-and-unsafe/). Just don't. Import your dependencies. Just do it the right way for the sake of your future self.